# Definition of non-singular curve

Tags: calculus, curves

A path $c:[a,b]→R$ is non singular if $c'(t)≠0$ for all $a≤t≤b$. This is the definition which was taught.However I am not sure if $c'(t)$ needs to be finite in the definition. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $R{}{}$?

Comment: Derivatives are always real numbers, und real numbers are finite. If the derivative exists in the first place, it can't be infinite, so the issue just doesn't come up at all.

Comment: R is the set of real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path is a continuous function, right? But if for some $\tau<\infty$ $$\lim_{t\to\tau} c'(t) = \infty,$$ it fails to be continuous.